# Как перебрать все возможные комбинации начиная с определенной

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Пытаюсь перечислить все возможные комбинации чисел
делаю это таким образом

```
for i in itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=9):
    
    id = "".join(i)
    print(id)
```

не очень понимаю, как начать перебор с определенного числа
т.е.
сейчас идет `000000001 - 999999999`
а как можно начать перебор к примеру c `00050000` и до `00060000`

Comment: `for i in map("{:0>9}".format, range(50000, 60000 + 1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```py
min = 50000
max = 60000
for i in map("{:0>9}".format, range(min, max + 1)):
    print(i)
```

См. [пример работы программы](https://ideone.com/zpVDkF) в Python. `"{:0>9}".format` означает, что числа будут выводиться как строки с 9 цифрами, заполненные нулями слева, если в числе меньше 9 цифр.